# What is Catalina.jar in Apache Tomcat Server ? How is it different from servlet-api.jar?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-3.0, catalina

I am trying to learn Servlet and Jsp(beginner). According to my tutor, there are two important jar files that tomcat server needs in order run our servlet web component. I want to know what are the work and difference between these two (catalina.jar and servlet-api.jar) jar files.

Answer (score 2):

Unzip them and look at the content: servlet.api.jar is the standardized API, e.g. contains `javax.servlet.*` classes and (especially) interfaces. catalina.jar contains `org.apache.*` classes, e.g. they're tomcat specific. I haven't checked enough to see if it's only interfaces or include implementations.

These two files are important, yes. But so are many other files that come with Tomcat. IMHO it's not worth wondering what's hidden in which file unless you're intending to develop tomcat itself or you're debugging deep into tomcat's implementation - an activity that you certainly won't do as a beginner.

Learn how work with the API and ignore what's in the implementation. And don't worry about the packaging. If the code you need is available, everything is fine.